# XAML Trigger on visibility of button setting focusmanager.focusedelement only fires once

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, triggers

I'm attempting to change focus in XAML based on the collapsed visibility of a button. The trigger will run the Converter I created once and not again. I am unable to use code behind and can't name the UIElements.

I've attempted quite a few things such as using a Datatrigger instead with the AutoCodeSuccess binding on visibility below. Again, it only will ever run the converter once. The binding on visibility of the button has no issues working so I assumed I could just use that property with Datatrigger.

```
                    <Button Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Visibility="{Binding AutoCodeSuccess, Converter={StaticResource ReverseBoolToVisCollapse}, FallbackValue=Visible}" Content="Auto-Code" Width="75" Command="{Binding AutoCodeClick}">
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed">
                                        <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource GetNextLogicalFocus}}"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>
                    </Button>
```

Here is the converter:

```
Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
    Dim curUIElement = DirectCast(value, UIElement)
    curUiElement.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next))
    Return FocusManager.FocusedElementProperty
End Function
```

Any suggestions that could get the datatrigger to work properly? I've checked my previous code involving datatriggers (not on visibility) and never had an issue before. This is in .NET Framework 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a workaround with `PredictFocus`, but you'll have to use directions (Up/Down/Left/Right) since Next is not a valid choice.

```
Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
    Dim curUIElement = DirectCast(value, UIElement)
    Return curUiElement.PredictFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Down)
End Function
```

Using the DataTrigger

```
<Button Grid.Column="2" Margin="5" Width="75" 
        Content="Auto-Code" Command="{Binding AutoCodeClick}">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AutoCodeSuccess}" Value="false">
                    <Setter  Property="Visibility" 
                             Value="Collapsed" />
                    <Setter  Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" 
                             Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                                     Converter={StaticResource GetNextLogicalFocus}}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Brilliant! I'm assuming based on your answer it had to do with the fact that visibility was bound and the datatrigger was also on visibility which probably unhooked the datatrigger after the first time it was used. Or, because the converter was setting focus as well as returning could have somehow unhooked the converter. Also, predictfocus is exactly what I was looking for with that converter. Just assumed it wasn't a thing and went the other direction with settings it which I was never fond of.